# Axios getting login page HTML source code instead of target url data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

i am trying to retrieve some data from my company Web API Service with Axios as following but I'm facing some issue.

**Code :**

```
axios.get("https://exampleurl.com/v1/scenarios/", {
    headers : {
        Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, text/html, */*'
    },
}).then(urlResonse => console.log(urlResonse))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

The response status is 200 but i'm getting the login service web page HTML source code as response. For your information, we have a Single sign-on (SSO) so no need (i think) to add auth option to axios get method configs.

When the request is sent, instead of using the URL **https://exampleurl.com/v1/scenarios/**, it redirects to **https://login_page.com/cas/login?service=https%exampleurl.com%v1%scenarios%** and send back its HTML source code.

Thank you

Comment: Is this from the same origin?

Comment: does server need credentials?

Comment: @Tarukami yes server need credentials

Comment: @mousetail https://login_page.com/cas/login is a central authentication service url and https://exampleurl.com/v1/scenarios/ is the url i want to retrieve data from